# How to disable Angular routerlink tabindex additions

Tags: angular, accessibility

The angular guide to accessibility does not mention how to NOT add tabindex on every `routerlink`'ed button.
My app ends up with `tabindex="0"` on buttons.

An accessibility expert told me it is better to not set tabindex than to set wrong attributes. But there seem to be no way to prevent that.
https://angular.io/guide/accessibility

I know how to add tabindex, but I have no idea how to say to angular and its router to NOT automatically add these attributes.

Comment: While `tabindex="0"` on a button or link is superfluous, it doesn't hurt anything as long as the value is 0.  If angular were adding a tabindex of 1 or 2 or any other positive value, **then** you'd have a problem.  While your accessibility expert is correct that you should avoid using tabindex, when possible, having it set to 0 on **interactive** elements is essentially a no-op.

Answer (score 3):

> I know how to add tabindex, but i have no idea how to say to angular and its router to NOT automatically add these attributes.

For your use case, as of now there is no way to tell Angular not to add `tabindex="0"` unless you yourself set the attribute value on the element.

I do understand, that the `button` element doesn't need an explicit `tabindex` attribute to be specified, as it already has `tabIndex` property value of `0` and is keyboard focusable. But having specified `tabindex="0"` on it shouldn't harm in any way.

#### Why Angular added tabindex when using routerLink on button element?

With the current implementation, when `routerLink` is used with the elements other than `<a>` and `<area>`, and if there is no `tabindex` attribute value set on that element, Angular will by default set `tabindex` attribute value of `0`.

[this.setTabIndexIfNotOnNativeEl('0');](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/df50af2bc5a562ceb1c3b80fef65c9eefb32cb72/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L192)

[setTabIndexIfNotOnNativeEl(newTabIndex)](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/df50af2bc5a562ceb1c3b80fef65c9eefb32cb72/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L199) method: Modifies the tab index if there was not a tabindex attribute on the element during instantiation.

There is already a long pending GitHub issue open regarding the same:

[routerLink directive always makes element focusable](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28345)